# Graph not working in matplot-Discrete distriubtion graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Would anybody be able to help me programme the following dataset using pandas and matplotlib to create a graph which looks like the one ive added or anything remotely similar. Any help would mean the world

[image: Dataset]

[image: Graph im trying to create]

[image: Dataset2]

```
df1=df.loc[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]
print(df1)

partNames=['Conservative', 'Labour', 'Lib Dem', 'SNP', 'Green Party',
           'Brexit', 'Plaid','Other']
results = {


        '18-19':[df1.loc[0, 'Groups' : 'Other']],
        '20-24':[df1.loc[1, 'Groups' : 'Other']],
        '25-29':[df1.loc[2, 'Groups' : 'Other']],
        '30-39':[df1.loc[3, 'Groups' : 'Other']],
        '40-49':[df1.loc[4, 'Groups' : 'Other']],
        '50-59':[df1.loc[5, 'Groups' : 'Other']],
        '60-69':[df1.loc[6, 'Groups' : 'Other']],
        '70+':[df1.loc[7, 'Groups' : 'Other']],
}


def survey(results, partNames ):

    labels = list(results.keys())
    data = np.arange(len(df1.Groups))
    data_cum = data.cumsum(axis=0)
    category_colors = plt.get_cmap('RdYlGn')(
    np.linspace(0.15, 0.85, data.shape[]))

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9.2, 5))
    ax.invert_yaxis()
    ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
    ax.set_xlim(0, np.sum(data, axis=1).max())

    for i, (colname, color) in enumerate(zip(partNames, category_colors)):
        widths = data[:, i]
        starts = data_cum[:, i] - widths
        ax.barh(labels, widths, left=starts, height=0.5,
                label=colname, color=color)
        xcenters = starts + widths / 2

        r, g, b, _ = color
        text_color = 'white' if r * g * b < 0.5 else 'darkgrey'
        for y, (x, c) in enumerate(zip(xcenters, widths)):
            ax.text(x, y, str(int(c)), ha='center', va='center',
                    color=text_color)
    ax.legend(ncol=len(partNames), bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1),
              loc='lower left', fontsize='small')

    return fig, ax


survey(results, partNames)
plt.show()
```

i keep on getting errors such as tuple index out of range or traceback errors, specifically in :np.linspace(0.15, 0.85, data.shape[]))

Comment: Please include your data as text, and also mention your attempt so far.

Comment: Hi quang, its not letting me add the code, but i have pretty much followed the matplotlib example code seen here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/horizontal_barchart_distribution.html

Comment: click `edit` below your post, or [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61643091/edit) to add your code.